# How can I add a URL link to my post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to add a podcast mp3 link to each post. Instead of copying and pasting the URL the four times it is linked around the page, I want to be able to create a custom input box (like Featured Image) so it can be pasted once and then referenced on the page code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about post_meta data - information stored about a page or post which is not part of the standard fields - title, content, image etc.

WP has support for post_meta built-in, but you might not be able to see it - perhaps the "custom fields" panel is hidden or you have create a new custom post type and not added [support](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_type_supports/) for custom fields.

Try the "screen options" in the top right, or check the features supported by the post type - if missing, you can add additional support either via `add_post_type_support` or updating the code used to register the post_type.

Custom field ( post_meta ) data can be retrieved using the `get_post_meta` function - the same data can be loaded once and re-used several times within the same template.